# Does django-sorcery support connection pooling?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, django-sorcery

I'm playing around with django-sorcery, and so far it looks to me like I'm only getting one persistent connection into the database.

Does django-sorcery support connection pooling? If so, how do I control the number of open connections available in the pool?

Comment: Do you run parallel sessions / queries? If not, there's no need to acquire more connections.

Comment: I'm not explicitly managing sessions at all, just running queries via the ORM (eg. Model.objects.all()). Am I meant to explicitly generate new sessions?

Comment: (and yes, I do mean to run many sessions/queries in parallel)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with django-sorcery, but if it is anything like the Flask-SQLAlchemy wrapper, then it'll handle sessions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design itself is similar to Flask-SQLAlchemy, except for the part that `django_sorcery.db.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` itself is a scoped session where by default it will use threadlocal scoped session.

If you're using the `django_sorcery.db.middleware.SQLAlchemyMiddleware`, you're all set for session per request, you'll get one session per request and middleware will remove it at the end of the request.

As for the connection pool, its managed by sqlalchemy itself. You can override connection pool configuration via connection url querystring or using `ALCHEMY_OPTIONS["engine_options"]` in database config, which will pass those to `create_engine`